# Insert javascript variable into a form on another page?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there's a good way to take a variable built in Javascript and then insert it into a form that's on another page.

My application is a survey:  I've got it so that at the end of the survey, all the results are displayed so they can look over their answers.  Now I want to have the user click a link and have the answers of the survey show up automatically in the body of the form where they'll then add their email and contact info and click "send."

Any ideas?

Knowing that this ISN'T possible is fine too...if not, what alternate methods might I accomplish the end result?

Comment: This would be best done with a server side technology. Is there a reason that you require JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden field in first page and change that value from javascript variable. When you post that page it can be another page where you need to display in form element.

**EDIT**

```
If you need without form in first page you need to link with hyperlink like below.
<a href='#' onClick='OpenPage()'> Go To Result </a>

<script>
var val=20 ; // say this is the value you want to pass to second page
function OpenPage ()
{
   window.location.href = "resultpage.php?param=" + val;
}
</script>
```

After you need to read that param in resultpage either with javascript through URL string or from server side  (in PHP $_GET).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This may be a very VERY dumb comment, but if the first page doesn't have a form (it's the second page with a form) then will this work?

Comment: be specific to your problem and please respect the response. I gave one alternate. You have to put form or not that you need to decide to achieve the output. It is possible without having the form in first page too. The logic you should change in onClick on the link tag. See my edit answer